# If else statement using foreach loop (Xml)

Tags: php, xml

When executed the result tend to repeat

the output is either : stringDogDogDogDogDogDog
or DogDogDogDogDogDogDog

while it should have been either string or Dog

```
<?php  
$name = $_POST['name']; //node
$search = $_POST['search']; //value to be search
$xml = simplexml_load_file("patient.xml");

foreach ($xml ->patients as $patients) {
if ($search == $patients -> $name ) {
    echo "string";      
}
elseif ($search != $patients -> $name ) {
    echo "Dog";

}}?>
```

Comment: Show your `patient.xml` file

Comment: Are you trying to search the file for at least one match and output string, otherwise output dog?

Comment: FYI - you don't need an `else if` in this situation, just simply `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is light on detail so my answer is purely based on my assumption of the desired functionality.

You have an XML file and you're searching a field for a given value. The XML file has multiple "patients" so you're looping through each one and testing whether there's a match.

If a match is found in the file you want to output "string", otherwise you want to output dog.

The reason you're seeing 'stringDogDog...' is because the conditional is executed on each of the "patients". There are multiple "patients" generating output.

In the example below I'm setting the default value to "Dog". Then if a match is found I'm updating the output variable.

```
// Default output should be dog.
$output = 'Dog';

foreach ( $xml->patients as $patients ) {
    if ( $search === $patients->$name ) {
        $output = 'string';
        break; // we have our match so stop the loop.      
    }
    // no else here or we're going to end up with the long output again...
}

echo $output;
```